# Do datastore transactions need rollback when saving or deleting?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

In the example for `dataset.runInTransaction` ([link](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/datastore/dataset?method=runInTransaction)), there is explicit error handling that occurs on `transaction.get(key,callback)`.

But on other operations, such as `transaction.save(entity)` or `transaction.delete(key)`, there are no callbacks, so really no way to handle errors. For example:

```
dataset.runInTransaction(function(transaction, done) {
  transaction.save({
      key: dataset.key(['Company', 123]),
      data: {}
  });
  transaction.delete(dataset.key(['Company', 456]));
  done();
}, function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

Does this mean there is no need to explicitly rollback the transaction?

Comment: While I also wonder if calling .rollback() is required on errored transactions, you are mistaken about .save() not having a callback.   See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/datastore/transaction?method=save

Comment: I believe transaction.save does not, but dataset.save does take a callback as last argument.

Comment: you are right, i filed an issue with their docs and they are fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to look up for the same issue but found the below question helpful.

[Please have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320065/gcloud-datastore-transaction-issue-using-nodejs?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of back-and-forth with the `gcloud-node` contributors on the issue tracker:

1. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/1120
2. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/633

basically all of the edits are done at the same time (once `done()` is called) so if any fail, the entire transaction will be aborted at that time.

what was confusing is that some operations like `transaction.get()` do have callbacks.  Basically the version of the entity returned by `transaction.get()` needs to match the version before the `.save()` or `.delete()` occurs (which again, takes place when `done()` is called)    if the version doesn't match, the transaction is automatically aborted.

using `transaction.rollback()` is still helpfull if something in your `.get()` call doesn't match what your code expects.